# How will go to the nextpage after clicking an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I'm working with my application, this is the code.

Please help me to go in other page "Start Page" after clicking the "OK" button in AlertDialog.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             public void onTick(long millisUntilEnd) {
                 tv.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilEnd / 1000));
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this).create();
                // alertDialog1.setTitle("GAMEOVER");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog1.setMessage("Time's Up!");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog

                    // Setting OK Button
                    alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                            // closed
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    //"You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog1.show();

                 tv.setText("Game Over");
             }
            }.start();
```

Thanks..

Comment: what do u mean by "start page", it is a activity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        ab.setMessage(msg);
        ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent in=new Intent(context, ExportActivity.class);
                            context.startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        ab.create().show();
```

Here context is your Activity context if you are writing Alert message in another class. If you have your alert message in same class so you can pass "this" in place of context.

for same class replace

```
Intent in=new Intent(context, ExportActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(in);
```

by this

```
Intent in=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ExportActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
```

Here ExportActivity is that activity where you want to go.
please let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

write code here go other page

```
         alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        alertDialog1.dismiss();
    //then write code other page via intent
 Intent intent= new Intent(currentClassName.this ,otherClassName.class);
startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: the app will stop :( when i click the "OK" button in AlertDialog :(